# How to add $(...) in Docker Compose

Tags: jenkins, centos7, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a docker-compose.yml which contains the stuff to start a jenkins-server on CentOS7:

```
jenkins:
  image: jenkins
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker:ro
    - /usr/lib64/libsystemd-journal.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd-journal.so.0
    - /usr/lib64/libsystemd-id128.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd-id128.so.0
    - /usr/lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02
    - /usr/lib64/libgcrypt.so.11:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11
    - /usr/lib64/libdw.so.1:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdw.so.1
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

But I'm not able to run the compose because I keep getting an error on `$(which docker):/usr/bin/docker:ro`. How do I have to fix this?

Error: `ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "volumes" option in service "jenkins": "$(which docker):/usr/bin/docker:ro"`

Is it still not possible to include environment variables? I'm searching for the most right solution. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I escape a $ dollar sign in a docker compose file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619582/how-can-i-escape-a-dollar-sign-in-a-docker-compose-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$(...)` is not an environment variable, it's [command substituion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

You need to use an environment variable to pass in the value.

```
DOCKER_PATH=$(which docker) docker-compose up
```

docker-compose.yaml (snippet)

```
- ${DOCKER_PATH}:/usr/bin/docker:ro
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can escape the $ sign with $$, see here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution